# Appbarlayout scroll upward just when recyclerview scroll and not when user touch up the appbarlayout content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an AppBarLayout that contains a FrameLayout which is contains an ImageView . The FrameLayout itself is inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout.
In the bottom of AppBarLayout, there is a RecyclerView.

the code is as follow

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:id="@+id/root"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/img_video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cropper_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="#ff282828"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_video_view"/>
```

When a user touches up the AppbarLayout section, I don't want to scroll occurs. I want scroll up occurs just when user touches up the recyclerview.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. :-) 
According to my question, I wanted to pass touch event of AppBarLayout to ImageView that is inside of it. I overrided onInterceptTouchEvent of AppBarLayout,CollapsingToolbarLayout, and FrameLayout as following and returned false;

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
```

In this way, no one of parent views catches touch event and touch event will pass to ImageView.